# How to make JS button in Lightning

Tags: lightning, community

Is it possible to make a simple button on a lightning record page that would take a phone from a phone field from a record page (several buttons on leads\contacts\accounts\oppties record pages), append 'phone:' text to it and open the resulting text as a hyperlink, because we have an application which catches those phone: links and passes it to Cisco telephony for the call.
In Classic it was just a JS button with a simple

```
window.location.href='Phone:{!Contact.Phone}';
```

in it, but now it just doesn't work like that.
I can't do the quick URL action also, because it tells that URL format is not valid.
I heard it may be possibly done by Lightning component, but I just can' understand how. Is there some kind of example of how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I like this Bayforce document [Converting JavaScript Buttons for Lightning Experience](https://www.bayforce.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Bayforce-JavaScript-Lightning-Experience-White-Paper.pdf).

Winter '19 introduced [Enhancements to JavaScript Buttons in the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lecc_javascript.htm) - may not cover your case but worth investigating.

Comment: Thank you.Now I wrote this component, but get an "Uncaught SecureWindow.open supports http://, https:// schemes and relative urls." error. It must be because I try to execute window.open('Phone:{!Contact.Phone}','_blank' on a button press and Window component is locked for because of Locker service. Is it still possible to achieve openin gthat hyperlink?

Comment: <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:hasRecordId, force:appHostable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string"/>
     
    <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
        <!--Open URL in New Browser Tab With Record Id-->
        <lightning:button label="Open in New Window With RecordId" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleOpenNewWindowWithRecordId}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>

Comment: ({
   
    //Open URL in New Browser Tab With Record Id
    handleOpenNewWindowWithRecordId : function(component, event, helper) {
        var phonenumber = component.get('v.phone');
        window.open('Phone:{!Contact.Phone}','_blank');
    }
})